# Excel Formula to Change String to Date

Tags: mysql, excel, string, date, datetime

So I have 2 tables. In the first table the date is formatted as a string as follows `20030219`. In my second table I have the Date as `'2003-02-19'`. Is there a function that I can use to change the first tables strings to what I have in my second table.
This is for a query where I can pull results from both tables.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula, using the `DATE` function.  It assumes the string is in cell A1, and also assumes the string is always yyyymmdd (so always contains leading zeroes).

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1, 4), MID(A1, 5, 2), RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the result to be a string.

Let cell A1='20030219  (entered as a string in Excel)

This formula should work: =LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),2)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,2)

Comment: Thanks for your help